# How to check if a RadioButton was checked from another class?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm making a GUI in PyQt5 where there are multiple tabs. In one of the tabs, users select a radio button with what type of data they are entering.

This information changes what buttons are available in other tabs and I'm having trouble getting this information passed from the original tab class. I'd like to see if a radio button is checked from another tab and if it is, enable a button.

I have a function to return a string depending on which radio button is selected, but when I call the getDataType() function from the other tab, I get the error "AttributeError: module 'DataTab' has no attribute 'getDataType.'"

I've tried moving the getDataType() function outside of the DataTab class, but since the radio buttons use "self," I'm not able to access them.

I've also tried making a new class and calling that new class from the function, but then I get stuck on how to get the information to my other tab.

So in this example, once a user selects a radio button in the Data Tab, I want the corresponding push button on the Analysis Tab enabled.

When I uncomment the call to getDataType(), I get the following error: "AttributeError: module 'DataTab' has no attribute 'getDataType'"

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem,
                             QLineEdit, QFileDialog, QRadioButton, QGroupBox, QPushButton,
                             QGridLayout, QButtonGroup, QApplication, QAbstractItemView,
                             QTabWidget)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
import sys, os


class TabPage(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setStyleSheet('font: 15pt Tw Cen MT')
        self.show()
        # Creating the tabs here to have a reference
        self.tabWidget = QTabWidget()
        self.tabWidget.addTab(DataTab(), "Data Input")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(AnalysisTab(), "Analysis")

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

# The DataTab class holds all the GUI for the DataTab
class DataTab(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)

        self.layout = QGridLayout()

        self.intervalRadioButton = QRadioButton("Interval")
        self.ordinalRadioButton = QRadioButton("Ordinal")
        self.frequencyRadioButton = QRadioButton("Frequency")

        self.submitButton = QPushButton("Submit Data")

        self.layout.addWidget(self.intervalRadioButton, 7, 0, 1, 3)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.ordinalRadioButton, 8, 0, 1, 3)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.frequencyRadioButton, 9, 0, 1, 3)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()


    def getDataType(self):
        if self.intervalRadioButton.isChecked():
            return "interval"
        elif self.ordinalRadioButton.isChecked():
            return "ordinal"
        elif self.frequencyRadioButton.isChecked():
            return "frequency"


class AnalysisTab(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)

        self.createChooseIntervalGroup()
        self.createChooseOrdinalGroup()
        self.createChooseFrequencyGroup()

        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.ChooseIntervalGroup, 0, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.ChooseOrdinalGroup, 1, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.ChooseFrequencyGroup, 2, 1)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()

    # The right side of AnalysisTab containing the buttons for
    # analysis
    def createChooseIntervalGroup(self):
        self.ChooseIntervalGroup = QGroupBox("Tests for Interval Data")

        self.analyzeIntervalButton = QPushButton("Analyze")
        self.analyzeIntervalButton.setEnabled(False)

        # if DataTab.getDataType() != "interval":
        #     self.analyzeIntervalButton.setEnabled(True)

        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.analyzeIntervalButton, 1, 1)
        self.ChooseIntervalGroup.setLayout(self.layout)

    # The right side of AnalysisTab containing the buttons for
    # analysis
    def createChooseOrdinalGroup(self):
        self.ChooseOrdinalGroup = QGroupBox("Tests for Ordinal Data")

        self.analyzeOrdinalButton = QPushButton("Analyze")
        self.analyzeOrdinalButton.setEnabled(False)

        # if DataTab.getDataType() != "ordinal":
        #     self.analyzeIntervalButton.setEnabled(True)

        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.analyzeOrdinalButton, 1, 1)
        self.ChooseOrdinalGroup.setLayout(self.layout)

    # The right side of AnalysisTab containing the buttons for
    # analysis
    def createChooseFrequencyGroup(self):
        self.ChooseFrequencyGroup = QGroupBox("Tests for Frequency Data")

        self.analyzeFrequencyButton = QPushButton("Analyze")
        self.analyzeFrequencyButton.setEnabled(False)

        # if DataTab.getDataType() != "frequency":
        #     self.analyzeIntervalButton.setEnabled(True)

        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.analyzeFrequencyButton, 1, 1)
        self.ChooseFrequencyGroup.setLayout(self.layout)

def run():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    tabPage = TabPage()
    tabPage.show()
    app.exec_()

run()
```

Comment: I just did! I hope that helps clear things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution for this case is to use the signals to notify the change of status of the QRadioButton to enable or disable the button.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QWidget,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QRadioButton,
    QGroupBox,
    QPushButton,
    QGridLayout,
    QButtonGroup,
    QApplication,
    QTabWidget,
)


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setStyleSheet("font: 15pt Tw Cen MT")

        self.data_tab = DataTab()
        self.analysis_tab = AnalysisTab()

        self.tabWidget = QTabWidget()
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.data_tab, "Data Input")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.analysis_tab, "Analysis")

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)

        self.data_tab.intervalRadioButton.toggled.connect(
            self.analysis_tab.analyzeIntervalButton.setEnabled
        )
        self.data_tab.ordinalRadioButton.toggled.connect(
            self.analysis_tab.analyzeOrdinalButton.setEnabled
        )
        self.data_tab.frequencyRadioButton.toggled.connect(
            self.analysis_tab.analyzeFrequencyButton.setEnabled
        )


class DataTab(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.intervalRadioButton = QRadioButton("Interval")
        self.ordinalRadioButton = QRadioButton("Ordinal")
        self.frequencyRadioButton = QRadioButton("Frequency")
        self.submitButton = QPushButton("Submit Data")
        layout.addWidget(self.intervalRadioButton, 7, 0, 1, 3)
        layout.addWidget(self.ordinalRadioButton, 8, 0, 1, 3)
        layout.addWidget(self.frequencyRadioButton, 9, 0, 1, 3)


class AnalysisTab(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.createChooseIntervalGroup()
        self.createChooseOrdinalGroup()
        self.createChooseFrequencyGroup()

        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.ChooseIntervalGroup, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.ChooseOrdinalGroup, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.ChooseFrequencyGroup, 2, 1)

    def createChooseIntervalGroup(self):
        self.ChooseIntervalGroup = QGroupBox("Tests for Interval Data")
        self.analyzeIntervalButton = QPushButton("Analyze")
        self.analyzeIntervalButton.setEnabled(False)
        layout = QGridLayout(self.ChooseIntervalGroup)
        layout.addWidget(self.analyzeIntervalButton, 1, 1)

    def createChooseOrdinalGroup(self):
        self.ChooseOrdinalGroup = QGroupBox("Tests for Ordinal Data")
        self.analyzeOrdinalButton = QPushButton("Analyze")
        self.analyzeOrdinalButton.setEnabled(False)
        layout = QGridLayout(self.ChooseOrdinalGroup)
        layout.addWidget(self.analyzeOrdinalButton, 1, 1)

    def createChooseFrequencyGroup(self):
        self.ChooseFrequencyGroup = QGroupBox("Tests for Frequency Data")
        self.analyzeFrequencyButton = QPushButton("Analyze")
        self.analyzeFrequencyButton.setEnabled(False)
        layout = QGridLayout(self.ChooseFrequencyGroup)
        layout.addWidget(self.analyzeFrequencyButton, 1, 1)


def run():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    tabPage = Widget()
    tabPage.show()
    app.exec_()


run()
```